# Angular app $http request to node app on localhost

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm running a nodejs app on localhost:3000.  I have a front-end tutorial angular page that calls localhost like this...

```
  $scope.msg = 'requesting';
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/'
  }).then(function(response) {
    $scope.msg = response;
  }, function(response) {
    $scope.msg = 'err ' + JSON.stringify(response);
  });
```

I can see from the console on my node app that it is answering with 200 and a json object `{foo:'bar'}`.  But the `$scope.msg` variable ends up looking like this...

```
err {  
   "data":null,
   "status":-1,
   "config":{  
      "method":"GET",
      "transformRequest":[  
         null
      ],
      "transformResponse":[  
         null
      ],
      "url":"http://localhost:3000/",
      "headers":{  
         "Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"
      }
   },
   "statusText":""
}
```

Why would the client think there's a problem when the server produced a good response?  Running the request in the browser works fine.

Loading the angular page (http://localhost:9000) the browser dev tools, I see this...

[image]

**But for some reason, the response tab is empty**.  When I make the same request (http://localhost:3000/) with the browser and watch, I see the JSON in the response tab.

Comment: What do you see in the browser console? Are you fighting the Same-Origin Policy?

Comment: @SLaks does same host, different port count as same origin?

Comment: @SLaks... ahh.  the console! yes, it does indicate an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource. ... is therefore not allowed.  I'm going to google that now to see if I can learn how to fix.  Thanks for the helpful tip.

Comment: Basically you need to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to `localhost:9000` on server side. (Although, if you host it on localhost only, not publicly, you can just set it to `*`.)

Comment: @JohnSmith - big help, Thanks!  Do you want to make that an answer so I can check it off?

Comment: Well, I've done it, however @SLaks deserves the credit just as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **SLaks** mentioned in the comment, it happens because of the Same-Origin Policy. Your node app is running on `localhost:3000`, while your client is on `localhost:9000`.

You'll need to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on server side to allow requests coming from `localhost:9000`.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your server reply with a correct content type header:

```
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
```